# Livestream desktop to Debian VPS via VLC

Tags: windows, desktop, vlc-media-player, streaming, vps

I want to stream my desktop to a VPS, where everyone can see it without additional software.
My Computer runs on Win7, the VPS on Debian. I already set up VLC on the VPS, and the webinterface is working (although it's pretty ugly, in my opinion). But how can I tell the server now to accept the stream from my desktop? I know that I can stream my desktop with VLC with the input Screen://, but how can I send it to the server / how am I supposed to authorize so that only specific people can upload to the server?
Also, how do I make the Webinterface of VLC look nicer (I only need the streaming window)

Comment: Are you trying to play the stream on your VPS or restream it so others can play it?

Comment: I want to send the stream from my desktop to the VPS, which then re-streams it to everyone on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the server to accept your desktop's stream all depends on how your desktop is streaming (what is the transport?  HTTP, RTSP, MMSH, etc.).

As for the HTTP interface, it would probably take some work, but you can change it.  On my Ubuntu box the default web interface is located in `/usr/share/vlc/http`.  You should be able to copy the files out of that directory and make whatever changes you want.  You can then go to the preferences window.  Make sure all the preferences are being shown.  Go to Interface->Main Interfaces->HTTP and set the *Source Directory* to the directory containing your changes.

Comment: I didn't choose a transport method yet, and VLC gives me the opportunity to stream with all protocols. Which protocol would you recommend? And how does the server know that he can accept this stream (or does the server accepts every stream?)

Comment: Approached this the wrong way all along, thanks for the help though!